# How to increment a value in MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, increment

I am trying this code, but it isn't working.

The main problem is in these variables or in the script given at the bottom.

```
  <?PHP
  $upVote1 = "UPDATE facerate SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE Picture = '".$idOptain1."'";
  $upVote2 = "UPDATE facerate SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE Picture = '".$idOptain2."'";

  $upIgnore1 = "UPDATE facerate SET ignores = ignores + 1 WHERE Picture = '".$idOptain2."'";
  $upIgnore2 = "UPDATE facerate SET ignores = ignores + 1 WHERE Picture = '".$idOptain1."'";
  ?>

  <img onClick='renderData1()' src="<?php echo $img1['Picture'] ?>" />
  &nbsp;
  <img onClick='renderData2()' src="<?php echo $img2['Picture'] ?>" />

  <!-- £££££££££££££££ SCRIPT HERE ££££££££££££££ -->
  <script>

  function renderData1()
  {
  document.write(<?php mysql_query("$update1, $upIgnore1") or die(mysql_error()); ?>);
  };

  function renderData2()
  {
  document.write(<?php mysql_query("$update2, $upIgnore2") or die(mysql_error()); ?>);
  };

  </script>
```

Comment: You seem to have the right syntax for the `update` of incrementing a value.  What is your problem?

Comment: actually i have set up images, when someone will be clicking on a image, the image will be getting a +1 increment in a votes field, so here's the code and when i am clicking, the database is not updating!

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and JS like that. The easiest solution would be sending and Ajax request to a PHP script which runs the query. At the moment, the query will be executed on pageload - not on click

Comment: You need to send Ajax request to you server to execute something in PHP. You cannot do any php on client side

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query does not support multiple queries. You will need to break it up into a single query per call.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up some Ajax request to register user votes: This might give you some idea how to do it (using jQuery here):

Javascript function to execute on vote click event :

```
function upvote_picture(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'vote.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            picture_id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**vote.php** file:

```
<?php 
// Any error or warning in this script will break JSON response !

function send_json($array)
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($array);
    exit();
}

// Add query execution status variables and messages here
$response = array();

$id = !empty($_POST['picture_id']) ? $_POST['pciture_id'] : FALSE;

if($id){

    // Do you query here
    if ( mysql_query(....)) {
        $response['success'] = TRUE;
    } else {
        $response['success'] = FALSE;
    }
} else {
    $response['success'] = FALSE;
}

send_json($response);

?>
```